# How update models modelforms and django

Tags: python, django, templates, modelform

i have a problem when i try update the data for model usuario

this is my model

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(User)
 nombres = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
 correo = models.EmailField()


 class Meta:
    db_table = u'utp_users'


 def __str__(self):
    return str(self.nombres.encode('utf-8')  )
```

this is mi form. py

```
class UsuarioForm(forms.ModelForm):

 class Meta:
     model = Usuario
     fields = ['nombres','correo']
```

my url

```
url(r'^menu/update/(?P<usuario_id>\d+)$', 'utpapp.views.update'),
```

this my view update

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def update(request,usuario_id):



 form = UsuarioForm(request.POST)

 if form.is_valid():

     user = Usuario.objects.get(pk=usuario_id)
     form = UsuarioForm(request.POST, instance = user)
     form.save()
     return redirect('/menu/')
 else:
     user = Usuario.objects.get(pk = usuario_id)       
     form = UsuarioForm(instance=user)

 return render_to_response('form.html',{ 'form':form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and the template i am do this

```
<a title="Editar informacion" href="/menu/update/{{usuario.id}}"><img src="/media/imagenes/usuario.png" class=" col-xs-3 col-md-7 quitar-float" alt="Editar informacion" ></a>
```

the problem is when i select the option update i get the this msj "Page not found (404)"

but i change in template href {{usuario.id}} for {{user.id}} is work but with user different what is the problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you need to pass `usuario` as context to the template, and you can much simplify the code (especially the form for GET/POST, they are basically the same form, so don't repeat it) as like:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required(login_url='/')
def update(request,usuario_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(Usuario, pk=usuario_id)
    form = UsuarioForm(request.POST or None, instance=user)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
       form.save()
       return redirect('/menu/')
    # you need to pass `usuario` as part of the context to template
    # so you can access usuario.id in template
    return render_to_response('form.html',{ 'form':form, 'usuario': user }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Also make sure you have a `url` route for `/menu/`, or else `redirect` will get you `404`.

Comment: ohh interesting your answer but when i select option the url will not  Recognizes the usuario.id but i  when write in  url of the browser  the a  any id and it works

Comment: @papo, what do you mean when you say "i select option the url will not Recognizes the usuario.id"? Can you explain it a little more, what url you're in, what select option?

Comment: @papo, are you saying that, on url `/menu/update/{{usuario.id}}` the `<a>` link not showing the correct `usuario.id`? Or you're actually at `/menu/update/` and want to show the link with `{{usuario.id}}`? You will need another url route, view and template for `/menu/update/` in latter case.

Comment: thx you  i understand my error and can fix this with you answer :D

Answer (score 1):

You forget to pass the `usuario` variable to the template.

Comment: but dont understand how pass the usuario in template, when user no is necesary and it works

Comment: `user` is set in the `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` context processor: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth

Comment: The `usario` variable should be passed as any other var in the `render_to_response()` or `render()` call.

Comment: @catavaran, sorry I didn't realize you have already answered this question while I typed, I should of just add comment on your answer instead.